# I want to print a parttern of X or * using while loop. it should look like

Tags: java, output

```
    *
  *****
*********
*********
*********
*********
```

here is my code but it is not working

```
final int WIDTH = 6;
final int HEIGHT = 9;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (i < HEIGHT * 2 && j < WIDTH) {

  if ((i + (i % 2) + (WIDTH) / 2) < j // right slope
        || (i + (i % 2) + j) < (WIDTH) / 2)// left slope
  {
    System.out.print(" ");
  } 
  else {// solid then
    System.out.print("*");

  }
}

System.out.println();
i+=2;
j++;
```

Comment: So, what does it output?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you incrementing `i` and `j` after the printing has completed? This looks like an infinite loop...!

Comment: this is java, not C right?

Comment: the output is a infinite loop, it keeps printing space

Comment: You must increment within the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your incrementers i and j are currently outside your while loop closing bracket (}).
Since they are never incremented, the while condition never hits.
Common mistake that is causing an infinite loop.

Also the + (i % 2) part of your if conditional is pointless since you are incrementing i by 2 each time as any even number % 2 is 0.

My suggestion is to trace the code by hand, start with smaller values perhaps, but this will help you understand what is going wrong.

Comment: even if I put inside the while loop it only print
**

Comment: thank you. so whenever I encounter problem like printing the house of star, how should i approach the problem?

Comment: you should go through the logic keeping track of the values on paper, and writing the output on paper as well.  This will show you exactly where your logic is flawed and most likely give you a nice "Aha" moment when you see what you have been doing.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you must increment the values in your `while()` loop if you don't wish it to be infinite. So, perhaps add them in at the bottom!

```
while (i < HEIGHT) {

  if (i == 0) {
    System.out.print("    *");
  } else if (i == 1) {
    System.out.print("  *****");
  } else {// solid then
    System.out.print("**********");
  } System.out.println("");
  i++;
}
```

Edit: I also changed your check conditions to make them simpler. If you only have to print this one shape it should be fine, but if you will be making a variety of sizes you will need to improve your algorithm!